# Mesh became grey when I recalculated normals, can't fix it

Tags: normals

So I was cleaning up an object in blender (mold I'm making of an eyelid to 3d print and pour silicone into) and things started going haywire.  I filled a hole in some faces and the new face became purple (In solid mode, whether in object/edit mode) and I read online that could be because the faces didn't align properly.  So anyhow I selected everything and recalculated normals, and now my mesh is dark grey (Pictured)
[image]

I read that dark grey faces could be directly because of the normals (make sense) but I can't fix it!  I'll recalculate them, look at them in face orientation mode, etc..   and they're still dark grey.  Help!

Blend file if you're interested:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Isnt that because of material setup? (viewport color, second material slot) Please attach your blend via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: I had read that on other answers on here (that it could be because of material setup) but neither object in here has materials, and one isn't dark grey.  I just tried to attach the blend on that link, THINK its processing at the moment?

Comment: It's not processing... it's waiting for you to press "upload"

Comment: @ChristopherBennett it is processing after you hit upload. JoeCrozier - try it again ...

Comment: @vklidu Its uploaded now, was giving me heck last night

Comment: Check Custom Normals

Comment: Search for "Reset Vectors" operator

Comment: @vklidu  The reset vectors did it!  Do you want to "answer" it so I can accept that answer?  P.s. what the heck is that?

Comment: Thank you, happy to hear you solve it,. Your Q is quite common, so I guess it would be closed as duplicate anyway. I was lazy to search for similar, it is not always easy to find it here. If you want to answer you are welcome :) Also you can flag the comment so others can see it was helpful.

Comment: Per @vklidu's comments, the "reset vectors" operator did it, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Go into your objects Data tab and click "Clear Custom Split Normals Data"
This should help it look correct within Blender.

[image: clear custom normal data]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

XRAY Top right side of the screen.  That's what worked for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)